# How to use Existing typescript namespaced classes as external modules for nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, namespaces, typescript1.6

The simple question here is how do I use namespaced typescript classes as external modules for use in node. The answer to that seems to be

> It can't be done, don't try it, don't use namespaces

Well I am in the position that we have a large codebase that is all written in namespaces and we are now trying to use this code in node.js as well.

I am trying to figure out how to use our existing code.

I have got as far as compiling my namespaced code into a commonjs nodelibs folder that produces one `js` file and one `d.ts` for each `ts` file.

I have to add the following to each of my ts files that I want to be available to node:

```
namespace Organisation.Project.Entities{
    export class SomeThing{

    }
}

var module: {copy module definition from node.d.ts}

if(module)
{
    module.exports = Organisation.Project.Entities;
}
```

I can use this code in my node application:

```
var entities = require("../nodelibs/entities/entities");

var myThing = new entities.SomeClass();
```

despite there being both a `entities.js` and `entities.d.ts` at `../nodelibs/entities/entities` there is no type info or compile time checking that `SomeClass` is a thing.

I can manually import the references file and manually type the instance of the class but in my case `SomeClass` is a class with a lot of statics on it so I can't fingure out how to type it properly...

```
var entities = require("../nodelibs/entities/entities");

var classRef = entities.SomeClass;

var myVar = classRef.staticProperty;
```

In this example I can't type `classRef` as `SomeClass` as it isn't an instance of `SomeClass`, it's the class constructor.
How do I type classRef so that I can get access to the static properties on the class `Some Class`?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe with `import entities` instead of `var entities`?

Comment: Import gives various errors along the lines of cannot find module or entities.js is not a valid module...

Comment: In the imported file `entities.ts`, you should use the standard static ES6 syntax: `export namespace Organisation.Project.Entities { /* ... */ }`. After that, the compiler will be able to see it as a valid module.

Answer (score 1):

## Write the code with ES6 modules

In the module, use the static [ES6 module syntax](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/):

```
// File entities.ts
export namespace Organisation.Project.Entities {
    export class SomeClass {
        public static abc = 'abc';
    }
}
```

Then, import your namespace:

```
// File main.ts
import {Organisation} from './entities';
type classRef = Organisation.Project.Entities.SomeClass;
var myVar = classRef.abc;
```

## Compile for Node.js

Say the compiler to generate modules in the CommonJS format:

```
// File tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

## Compile for the browser

In a browser, you can use a bundler or a loader. There is some configuration to do.

Bundlers:

- [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) ([a tutorial here](http://www.jbrantly.com/es6-modules-with-typescript-and-webpack/));
- [Browserify](http://browserify.org/).

Loaders:

- [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) ([a tutorial here](http://david-barreto.com/how-to-use-typescript-with-systemjs/));
- [RequireJS](http://www.requirejs.org/).

Comment: So close! I thought that was going to fix it but if I add export to the namespace then I can't compile without modules for use in the browser (with outFile specified). This is how we currently compile our codebase, all into one file. Thanks

Comment: @Roaders : You can use a bundler (Webpack) or a loader (SystemJS) in order to work with a browser. I'll edit.